# SQL Server CE Database Connection Issues

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I have an application with a database called voodoobase.sdf. 
Using .NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5

I can see it in Server Explorer and connect to it fine from there. The DB File is located in:

> c:\Users\me\Documents\VisualStudio2010\Projects\testproj\voodoobase.sdf

The same named DB under Solution Explorer is said to reside at the same location.

> c:\Users\me\Documents\VisualStudio2010\Projects\testproj\voodoobase.sdf

Assuming they are the same... why can my application which compiles successfully alwways crash with a connection error:

```
SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.voodoobaseConnectionString);
dbCon.Open();
```

Throws an error on dbCon.Open() saying that could not get a connection to the SQL server. Let me know if further detail is required.

Comment: what is Properties.Settings.Default.voodoobaseConnectionString set to?

Comment: It is set to Copy Always but no different. voodoobaseConnectionString = Data Source=|DataDirectory|\voodoobase.sdf;Password=somepassword;Persist Security Info=True.

Comment: have you checked the formatting on http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce to make sure it is in the correct format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the SqlConnection class, but the **SqlCeConnection** class.